# Identify if the_post hook is being called from the admin post list

Tags: plugins, posts, hooks, redirect

I have added a custom hook that  for the_post that will redirect a post to another location when the user clicks on it. I have some checks in place so that in the menus of the site, it will display like it is an actual post, but when the user clicks on it, it will go to a completely different post.

The problem i have is that when i try to view the post list in the admin panel and there is a post on the list that has this meta field set. The list wont render. It looks like the if statement is reading true here and the die() is then preventing anything from working. How can i make it so the code knows it is in the admin area and will not redirect under these circumstances.

```
function checkpostredirect($post)
{
    if(is_single() && get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nb_postredirect', true ) != "" && is_admin() == false) 
    {
        wp_redirect(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nb_postredirect', true ));
        header('Location: '.get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nb_postredirect', true ));
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'checkpostredirect' );
```

Comment: `template_redirect` is a more logical action to use for this, and will eliminate the need to solve this problem.

Comment: this hook doesnt seem to trigger

Comment: It runs on every front end request, check the action reference codex page for an example. Another approach would be to filter permalink output and just output the correct link without having to do a redirect, which will save you an extra request and some processor cycles.